# boost::property_tree write_json in Unicode

Tags: c++, boost, unicode

I'm struggling to get Unicode output from Boost::property_tree as per code below:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
pt.put("name1", "Žluťoučký");
boost::property_tree::write_json(std::cerr, pt, false);
```

This returns:

```
{"name1":"\u00C5\u00BDlu\u00C5\u00A5ou\u00C4\u008Dk\u00C3\u00BD"}
```

Where I would like to see properly encoded as I need to pass it further:

```
{"name1":"Žluťoučký"}
```

Any help or suggestion appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that probably want to use the wide-string form, boost::property_tree::wptree instead (and put using wide-strings).  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/wptree.html

Comment: Thanks for this, very interesting feature. However this still doesn't solve my problem as:
- output becomes {"name1": "\u017Dlu\u0165ou\u010Dk?"} what is not passable further
- wptree doesn't consume anything except wstring, so no bool or numeric values

Comment: Did you change std::cerr to std::wcerr?

Comment: Yep, that was a must. It wouldn't even compile when trying to write it to std::cerr.

Comment: I'd also have to change input values to pre-empt those with "L" to indicate wide character.

Answer (score 1):

> Where I would like to see properly encoded as I need to pass it further

Your definition of "properly encoded" is arbitrary. If you use any compliant JSON parser on the other end you'll get the results as expected. You shouldn't care about the transport encoding, unless you're gonna **break into** the abstraction layer of JSON and interpret the bytes in the stream, which are an implementation detail.

There *might* be a flag, but I wouldn't count on it, since, indeed, JSON is only an "arbitrary" backend implementation for Property Tree in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for this, however I'm not too sure about this. I need to pass value outside of scope of this code (Mongoose -> HTTP -> SoapUI), where it seems to me that original type got discarted. So further passing would require a workaround to detect UTF again.

I did few check with [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) and it seem to do exactly what I need.

Comment: Nothing got discarded. Its representation just changed but it represents identical values

Comment: I agree that problem is in data representation and not in actual data itself. But that data representation is exactly what I need to keep.

I'm getting absolutely correct result when I output from code above with: 
    cerr << "name1: " << pt.get<string>("name1") << endl;

Comment: @blech this means you'll have to use something else that you can control the presentation of. Or patch boost: create_escapes is the function to overrule http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/boost/property_tree/detail/json_parser_write.hpp

Comment: I'm not sure now, does it mean that Boost is not doing well, or is not doing well for what I need it to do?

Comment: I don't see how you can be confused. I told you very clearly that you're relying on implementation details, apparently because your downstream JSON consumer is badly written. Your consuming code breaking the abstraction of JSON by requiring things that are irrelevant in the JSON spec (hence: not supporting JSON properly). So, indeed, boost might not do well /for what you need it to do/ (which is: not-JSON, albeit very similar)